# Python Selenium - Change Url Date

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to change the checkin and checkout date in the following url:
https://www.booking.com/hotel/fr/le-leman.fr.html?label=gen173nr-1DCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaCyIAQGYAQ24ARjIAQzYAQPoAQGIAgGoAgS4AuGugoYGwAIB0gIkODQyNzI0MzUtNzlmZi00ZTY1LWJkNGUtZmQyMGIxMGE3NzJl2AIE4AIB;sid=1a1526834c348b388f7097913631c2e3;checkin=2021-06-09;checkout=2021-06-10;sig=v11C1wtOKO

I thought about using a Regex rule to set today's date:

```
d = datetime.date.fromordinal(datetime.date.today().toordinal()-0).strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
url = driver.current_url
regex = r"^\d{4}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$"
result = re.sub(regex, d, url, 0)
if result:
    print (result)
```

But it's doesen't work.

Thank's you for your attention.

PS : SORRY I have a bad english..

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for this, you can simply try this:

```
import datetime

checkin_date = datetime.date.fromordinal(datetime.date.today().toordinal()-0).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
checkout_date = datetime.date.fromordinal(datetime.date.today().toordinal()-0).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
url = "https://www.booking.com/hotel/fr/le-leman.fr.html?label=gen173nr-1DCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaCyIAQGYAQ24ARjIAQzYAQPoAQGIAgGoAgS4AuGugoYGwAIB0gIkODQyNzI0MzUtNzlmZi00ZTY1LWJkNGUtZmQyMGIxMGE3NzJl2AIE4AIB;sid=1a1526834c348b388f7097913631c2e3;checkin="+checkin_date+";checkout="+checkout_date+";sig=v11C1wtOKO"
print(url)
```

And u can give the variables `checkin_date` and `checkout_date` the value you want and then use the url simply.

Answer (score 0):

Very HelpFull I try something else and still working well.

```
    # Selectionne la date d'aujourd'hui au format compatible booking
d = datetime.date.fromordinal(datetime.date.today().toordinal()+1).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
# Selectionne la date d'aujourd'hui +n au format compatible booking
d1 = datetime.date.fromordinal(datetime.date.today().toordinal()+2).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
# Variable pour préparer le changement sur booking
dformat = 'checkin=' + d
d1format = 'checkout=' + d1
# Selectionne l'url actuelle
url = driver.current_url
#Remplace le text de la date par la nouvelle
url = url.replace("checkin=2021-06-02", dformat)
url = url.replace("checkout=2021-06-03", d1format)
driver.get(url)
```

it also works, it's a little worse than yours but it's functional;)